# Can I tell AutoMapper how to pick between competing maps?

Tags: c#, automapper

Can AutoMapper have two mappings that are the same types, but somehow use one sometimes and the second other times?

Something like this is what I am thinking:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FunkyObject, Client>().ConvertUsing(new FirstConversionType());
Mapper.CreateMap<FunkyObject, Client>().ConvertUsing(new SecondConversionType());
```

I would like to do the above and somehow tell automapper when I do the mapping, which one to use.  Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you define the "sometimes" in one custom converter?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - Because there is no way to pass a parameter into the converter.  So the only way I can say when to use one type of conversion or the other is to modify my Classes.  Both are generated classes, so I would have to do it as a partial class (though that is not a big issue.)  But I would rather not add conversion flags to the classes as it is not really a concern of the class how it is converted.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Mapper.Reset();` before `Mapper.CreateMap<...>(...);`.